# Is accesssing an atomic struct containing two floats more efficient than accessing two seperatate atomic float variables when working with a high freq

Tags: c++

I am pulling sensor data at a high frequency (during some measurements 1ms, sometimes every 2/5/10 ms) and displaying them on the interface (live plot/gauges) in the same thread. Now that I am splitting it up into two threads for obvious efficiency reasons (the data display thread is accessing the shared variables only every 20 ms) I was wondering whether it would cause less delay for the data pulling thread to overwrite two separate threadsafe variables or one struct/object containing these two.

Comment: Anything stopping you from implementing both approaches, and benchmarking each one to see which one is better? This is something that does not have a single answer for every CPU, operating system, and every possible combination of hardware and software that's used in the world today. It's a given that some combination of hardware will be faster with one implementation, and the rest with the other.

Comment: I already tried it out, which is the exact reason why I am asking this question. Looking at the data timestamps after the measurement on lower-end systems (high end systems had no problem displaying data in the same thread) showed that both versions worked and there were not delays. The problem is that i do not have access to low-low-end systems (just edge cases) and therefore wanted to know in theory which one should yield better results.

Comment: The two designs do two different things. That's probably more important than which one is faster. With an atomic struct, when the writer changes both values, the reader will always see both changes. With separate atomic variables, the writer could change one of the variables, then the reader could read that new value and the old value of the other one, then the writer would write the new value of the second one.

Comment: @PeteBecker that is true yet I would prefer not delaying the data pulling even if that means that the interface will display a value 2ms older, to be honest.

Comment: That’s fine, as long as it’s a deliberate choice and not an accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking gcc on Intel as a baseline, if you look at the code over at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vYKsW7ch1), you can see that using a `struct` containing two `float`s is marginally more efficient.  This is because:

- The `struct` is small enough to be lock-free (which is important - locking a mutex is slow).
- Both `float`s can be retrieved from (or stored in) the `struct` in a single atomic operation.  If you use separate variables you have to perform two atomic operations, and atomic operations are typically slower than non-atomic ones.

If the `struct` were larger than 8 bytes, it would no longer be lock-free and separate variables are likely to be faster (up to some reasonable limit on the number of variables).